# Show navigation bar in swrevealviewcontroller

Tags: ios, swrevealviewcontroller

I am using [SWRevealViewController](https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController) for side menu in my app. While choose one of the menu `navigationbar` hides automatically. I want to show the navigation bar always. I have tried following codes in my `ViewController`'s `viewDidLoad()`.

```
self.revealViewController().navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = false
```

and

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = false
```

But both are not working.

I have followed https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8EFfPT3UeWs to implement [SWRevealViewController](https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController) in swift based app.

Comment: do u need the navigation bar in side menu

Answer (score 1):

Please Add a navigation controller between your sw_front navigation controller and view controller and hide the navigation bar of first navigation controller using attribute inspector. 
To add navigation controller you need to select view controller and go to 
Editor -> Embed In ->Navigation Controller

Answer (score 0):

Your Menu (rear)VC can control this if you have it there then it always there unless you hide.